# how can i make just the arm move?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

[image] im practicing weight painting and after parenting with automatic weights my model is all messed up and some things that shouldn't move when moving a bone do for ex those wings and bows how can i fix this?

heres a link to the blend file https://mega.nz/folder/kTo2nLbY#Dc4S5nd6z2C9Bx_dEUpc1g

Comment: Your model has 3 mesh objects. Automatic weights don't work well with separate meshes. Duplicate the model, join the objects, remesh it, and bind this to the rig with automatic weights. Unparent it again, and use the *Data Transfer* modifier for the 3 original mesh objects to transfer the weights. Also, Rigify has a metarig for the bone layout, But the final rig must be generated with the *Generate Rig* button. To have this work you must not delete any bones of the face. Or you must delete all face bones. It looks like you deleted some eyebrow bones and generation now fails.